# Saving only one field from REST web API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

Alright, I am just not getting my head around it.

Trying to save the only title of existing CMS Page from web API, but looks when I do that all other fields are gone null.

I am using postman:

**PUT URL:** `http://www.example.com/rest/all/V1/cmsPage/19`

**Body content:**

```
{"page":
    {
        "id":"19",
        "title": "My Title"
    }
}
```

This saves the title but also makes content and other fields empty.

**Is there a way to save/update only title (or only one field)?**

Comment: First fetch all fields all of this id then, Pass all other parameter in request then you can not get this issue.

Comment: I understand that, but this will slow the process for the services, like mobile apps, and if multiple users are updating diff fields as their need, this will clash.

Comment: Then you need to use GraphQL, else you have to go with this same approach